# django how to handel big file (image) uploads > 400MB

Tags: javascript, django, file-upload, progress-bar, swfupload

i never did that before. i'm sure, that i need a progress bar to keep to user informed. are there some advises which way i should go? use a flash uploader (swfupload) or a "cooler" way with XMLHttpRequest.

- https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload
- http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/

thanks for an advise!

Comment: Usually your server (apache/lighttpd/nginx) handles the progress, ajax is just used for polling the server status and passing the %/i to the view.. example: http://fairviewcomputing.com/blog/2008/10/21/ajax-upload-progress-bars-jquery-django-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.plupload.com/.
It's already have upload progress status. But don't forget to send csrf in request.
I'm using it on my shop at magnitofoto.ru: [image: http://i.imgur.com/jTGKD.png]